# Time not being assigned to DateTime variables

Tags: c#, linq, list, datetime

I am trying to assign Time for a list of DateTime variables.
But the time shows as 00:00:00 after i execute linq foreach.
Please let me know where i m going wrong. thanks in advance

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;    
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Where(d => d.Date == tpl.Item1).ToList();
lstdt.ForEach(d => d = d.Date + ts);
```

Comment: what exactly is the ts value?

Comment: I just updated the code. please have a look. ts is TimeSpan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
List<DateTime> lstdt = dates.Where(d => d.Date == tpl.Item1).ToList();
var myList = lstdt.Select(d => d.Date + ts).ToList();
```

or in one line

```
dates.Where(d => d.Date == tpl.Item1).Select(d => d.Date + ts);
```

You are assigning the value to `d` but that doesn't change the original date in the list

Using a traditional `foreach` your code would be:

```
foreach (var d in lstdt) {
     d = d.Date + ts;
}
```

which would assign the expected time to the variable `d` but wouldn't be changed in the list. With `linq` there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. It worked :)
i have another need. For each element in lstdt, i want to increase timespan by certain hours. how is it possible??
Eg: let's say ts is 09:00
foreach element it must assign 09:00 then 11:00 and so on..
it would be good if i will be able to do it while assigning time.

Comment: @PrabhuChandan that's a dfferent question, you should post a new question.